# How to display data from Excel sheet into a chart

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office, achartengine

Hi I have excel sheet contains data as follows:

[image]

I want to plot a chart with X axis contains the Type and Y axis will have the number of occurrences. How can I come with that? Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Select your 2 column no of occurance and type e select chart:

[image]